# Doing Paint.SetColor() gradually with ValueAnimator leads to strange results

Tags: java, android, animation, ondraw

I want to set the Paint color gradually but it doesn't work the way it's supposed to. The paint color only changes if the item is selected by the user and is moving. Otherwise, the paint color doesn't change. What is causing this?

[image]

```
    @Override
public void onChildDraw(Canvas c, RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX, float dY, int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive) {

    if (actionState == ACTION_STATE_SWIPE) {
        if (optionsState == OptionState.UPVOTE) {
            drawUpvoteOption(c, viewHolder.itemView, dX);
        } else if (optionsState == OptionState.DOWNVOTE) {
            if (!isRightSwipeMaxed(dX)) drawDownvoteOption(c, viewHolder.itemView, dX);
            else drawDownvoteOption(c, viewHolder.itemView, MAX_RIGHT_SWIPE);
        }

        setTouchListener(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
    }

    if (dX == 0) {
        optionsState = OptionState.NONE;
    }

    if (!isRightSwipeMaxed(dX)) {
        super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
    } else {
        super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, MAX_RIGHT_SWIPE, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
    }
}

private void drawDownvoteOption(Canvas c, View itemView, float dX) {
    rightRect.set(itemView.getRight() + dX, itemView.getTop(), itemView.getRight(), itemView.getBottom());
    setRightPaintColorAnimate(Color.RED);
    c.drawRect(rightRect, rightPaint);
    drawText("DOWNVOTE", c, rightRect, rightPaint);
}

private void setRightPaintColorAnimate(int targetColor) {
    ValueAnimator colorAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofObject(new ArgbEvaluator(), rightPaint.getColor(), targetColor);
    colorAnimator.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    colorAnimator.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);
    colorAnimator.setDuration(300);
    colorAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
            //This only works if the item is currently moving
            rightPaint.setColor((int) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue());
        }
    });
    colorAnimator.start();
}
```